# Load a loading.gif image and disable all succeeding dropdowns until ajax load is complete

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have multiple dropdowns. The succeeding dropdowns are changed according to the just preceeding dropdown change. I want to load a loading.gif image and disable all other preceeding dropdowns till the ajax load is complete. New to jquery ajax so couldn't understand  many answers matching my question. Any help appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#zone').change(function(){
            var x=$('#zone').val();
            $.ajax({
                    type:'POST', url:"<?php echo site_url().'dealer/getDistrict';?>", data:'valuezone='+x, success:function(data){
                    $('#district').html(data);      
                    }           
                });
            });
        $('#district').change(function(){
            var y=$('#district').val();
            //alert(y)
            $.ajax({
                    type:'POST', url:"<?php echo site_url().'dealer/getTown';?>", data:'valuedistrict='+y, success:function(data){
                    $('#town').html(data);

                    }           
                });
            });
        $('#town').change(function(){
            var z=$('#town').val();
            //alert(z)
            $.ajax({
                    type:'POST', url:"<?php echo site_url().'dealer/getLoca';?>", data:'valuetowns='+z, success:function(data){
                    $('#loca').html(data);  
                    }           
                });
            });
        $('#loca').change(function(){
                var y=$('#loca').val();
                //alert(y)
                $.ajax({
                        type:'POST', url:"<?php echo site_url().'dealer/getDealer';?>", data:'valuetown='+y+', '+$('#town').val()+', '+$('#district').val(), success:function(data){
                        $('#result').html(data);

                        }           
                    });
                });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Are they all next to each other?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a loading gif as like this

```
 $('#zone').change(function(){
           $('loader').show(); //MAKE ANY OTHER THING VISISBLE

            var x=$('#zone').val();
            $.ajax({
                    type:'POST', 
                     url:"<?php echo site_url().'dealer/getDistrict';?>",                     
                    data:'valuezone='+x, 
                 success:function(data){
                                        $('loader').hide(); // SET THEM HIDDEN
                                        $('#district').html(data);      
                    }           
                });
            });
```

select element has a disabled attribute 
you disable all the select elements like this

```
$('select').attr('disabled','true');
```

and enable them using

```
$('select').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: This will make the other drop downs invisible *after* the AJAX call is ready. You should place the `.hide()` call directly into the `ajax()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the AJAX function on `onchange` of dropdown to populate the child dropdowns. In that case you can add a JavaSript function on `onchange` which shows the loader image first and  then call the AJAX function to populate the child dropdowns by deyaing 1 second so that, page loads the loader image before the AJAX call starts.

```
<td>
    <select name="company" id="company" 
            style="width:350px; height:145px;" 
            multiple="multiple"  
            Onchange="fnDelay('company','val1','val2');" >
    </select>
</td>
```

In the JavaScript function make the AJAX call delayed by 1 sec to show the loader image

```
function fnDelay(element, val1, val2) {
    $('##divLoading').show();
    // set time out by 2 second so that AJAX call gets delayed by 2 second.              
    // It gives time for loader image to get dispalyed.
    setTimeout(function() {
        fnSetChildDropDownValues(parentEle, val1, val2);
    }, 2000);
}
```

On HTML side define the loader inside a div as below. It also prevents the user from doing any action while its loading.

```
<div style="display:block;position:relative;">
    <form>
        Add HTML for dependentdropdowns....

        <div id="divLoading" style="background-color:##efefef; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; display:none; position:absolute; text-align:center; valign:middle; opacity:0.8; filter:alpha(opacity=80);">
            <br>
            <h1>Retrieving Data</h1><br>
            <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" border="0">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Hide the loader once the AJAX function is processed and child dropdowns are populated.

```
function fnSetChildDropDownValues(parentEle, attrVal1, attrVal2){

    //Add Logic that makes the ajax call and populates drop down
    .......
    .......
    $('##divLoading').hide();

    enter code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for the loader the jquery ajax global callback

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#loader").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loader").hide();
});
```